# is the Windows Explorer a shell

Tags: windows, shell, operating-system

Just started to read **Bash Cookbook, 2nd Edition** and got confused about this statement.

"Every modern operating system has at least one shell, and some have many. Some shells are command line–oriented, such as the shell discussed in this book. Others are graphical, like **Windows Explorer** or the **Macintosh Finder**."

Can you clarify how Windows Explorer is classified as a shell since it only focuses on file management.
P.S. I know shells can either be a CLI or GUI.

Research a ton but got no definite answers.

Comment: You're right to be confused, so I am. _"The shell is a command language interpreter."_ so it doesn't make any sense to call those apps shells.

Comment: The primary role of the shell is to give the user the ability to launch so-called shell commands and applications.  Explorer launches applications and command shells,at the behest of the user., doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

That of course depends on your definition of "shell". Some only consider command line/terminal shells as a shell. Others also include graphical user interfaces as shells.

Explorer.exe complicates matters a bit since it is responsible for the taskbar/desktop and also the file browser.

Microsoft clearly considers Explorer as a shell:

- The `shell` value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` defaults to Explorer.exe
- In the original Windows 95 design, most of the taskbar and file explorer code lived in shell32.dll. This was true up until Windows 8 when the UWP infection started, some of the shell code lives in other places now but a fair amount remain in shell32.